# How to autoexecute ipython notebook cells just like in Mathcad

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

In Mathcad Prime 2 you have this feature where if you change anything at the top of a worksheet it *automatically* recomputes all subsequent formulas that are affected by the correction. It figures out which of the formulas are now affected by this change and recomputes *only* those formulas, leaving everything else intact.

Is there a way to do the same thing in ipython. If I change a cell, ipython should first find out which other cells now contain wrong results and have to be recomputed. Then it should automatically recompute only those cells.

Answer (score 1):

Cells/Notebooks have no knowledge of dependencies, but you can use the kernel restart, and cell run-all or run all-below to refresh all the notebook.